# Xenial 16.04.1 LTS root filesystem mounted read only

Tags: boot, server, mount, services, systemd

I recently upgraded my physical server from 14.04.4 upstart based system to 16.04.1 systemd based system and find the root filesystem mounted as read only after booting. dmesg reveals what looks to me like a possible root-cause below:

```
[    6.994280] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    7.020103] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:(null)
[    9.444360] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    9.449201] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86.
[    9.506555] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <bigdawg>.
[   13.069691] systemd-sysv-generator[1153]: Unknown unit type for unit 'systemd-journald-dev-log.socket'
[   14.647188] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found ordering cycle on local-fs-pre.target/start
[   14.649431] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found dependency on systemd-remount-fs.service/start
[   14.651511] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found dependency on scsitools-pre.service/start
[   14.653509] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found dependency on readahead-desktop.service/start
[   14.655433] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found dependency on ebtables.service/start
[   14.657310] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
[   14.659141] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Found dependency on local-fs-pre.target/start
[   14.660924] systemd[1]: local-fs-pre.target: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job systemd-remount-fs.service/start
[   14.662698] systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Job systemd-remount-fs.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs-pre.target/start
```

I have checked the media with smartctl long test and all seems to be fine.

What would be my next step in debugging this?

Comment: Seems the issue might have been related to the system being only partially upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. I upgraded the packages that were held back with "apt-get dist-upgrade" and the issue has gone away.

Comment: Issue has returned - still can't identify what triggered the root filesystem to be mounted Read-Only. Anyone else had a similar issue?